# Add html asynchronously

Tags: html

I want to add new html in page asynchronously like

```
$.each(programListAll, function (j, innerItem)
{
      programHtml = '<div class="row"><ul>';
      $("#programList").append(programHtml);
});
```

It should show user that html is adding asynchronously.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a little delay in adding the items, the code would look like this:

```
var $programHtml = $('<ul class="row"></ul>');
$('#programList').append($programHtml);
var delay = 1000;

$.each(programListAll, function (j, innerItem)
{
   $programHtml.delay(j * delay).append('<li'> + innerItem + '</li>');
});
```

Comment: Thank you daniel. I have this idea in my mind, but i thought if there is any build-in feature which i am unaware of.